# Should I use NodePort in my Traefik deployment on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

According to [Traefik's Kubernetes guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/), I should use a Service of type **NodePort** to expose Traefik (YAML file [here](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/examples/k8s/traefik-deployment.yaml)). However, if I do that, how do I expose one of the IPs from my cluster to the outside world?

At this moment, I have edited the example [traefik-deployment.yaml](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/examples/k8s/traefik-deployment.yaml) file to be a **LoadBalancer** instead, and it seems to work just fine with the IP that the load balancer provides. What am I missing?

Comment: Traefik recommends NodePort because it's available on every k8s setup (cloud/bare-metal).
LoadBalancer are provided by a cloud provider. It is usually better to use a LoadBalancer rather than a NodePort.

Comment: This looks like to be the correct answer, but it is a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are valid approaches. The Kubernetes guide basically makes one proposal to set things up (with somewhat of a focus on the local minikube configuration). If you have found a path that's more convenient for you, by all means feel free to stick to it.

FWIW, one concern I sometimes hear raised is that cloud-based LoadBalancers may become expensive much faster, whereas with a NodePort you have more control over how requests are routed into your cluster (at the price of reduced convenience).