# How to access kubernetes websites via https

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, portforwarding

I built my own 1 host kubernetes cluster (1 host, 1 node, many namespaces, many pods and services) on a virtual machine, running on a always-on server.

The applications running on the cluster are working fine (basically, a NodeJS backend and HTML frontend).
So far, I have a NodePort Service, which is exposing Port 30000:

```
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
traefik-ingress-service   NodePort    10.109.211.16    <none>        443:30000/TCP            147d
```

So, now I can access the web interface by typing `https://<server-alias>:30000` in my browser adress bar.

But I would like to access it without giving the port, by only typing `https://<server-alias>`.
I know, this can be done with the kubectl port-forwarding command:
`kubectl -n kube-system port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 svc/traefik-ingress-service 443:443`

This works. But it does not seem to be a very professional thing to do.

Port forwarding also seems to keep disconnecting from time to time. Sometimes, it throws an error and quits, but leaves the process open, which leaves the port open - have to kill the process manually.

So, is there a way to do that access-my-application stuff professionally? How do the cluster provider (AWS, GCP...) do that?

Thank you!

Comment: that's what ingress is for

Comment: Please take a look for different [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers) As we can see you have installed one of them so please follow [Traefik Controller](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/user-guide/kubernetes/) once installed and configured you should use Ingress resources with appropriate ingress class like: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`.

Comment: You can directly apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423312/how-do-i-test-a-clusterissuer-solver/58436097?noredirect=1#comment103215785_58436097) approach

Answer (score 1):

Using Ingress Nginx you can access to you website with the name server:

1. Step 1: Install Nginx ingress in you cluster you can flow this [link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)

After the installation is completed you will have a new pod

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS

nginx-ingress-xxxxx                     1/1     Running
```

And a new Service

```
NAME                             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP
nginx-ingress                    LoadBalancer   10.109.x.y     a.b.c.d
```

2. Step 2 : Create new deployment for you application but **be sure that you are using the same name space for nginx ingress svc/pod and you application** and you set the svc type to **ClusterIP**
3. Step 3: Create Kubernetes Ingress Object

Now you have to  create the ingress object

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: **Same Name Space**
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your DNS  <server-alias>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc Name
          servicePort: svc Port
```

Now you can access to your website using the .

To create a DNS for free you can use [freenom](https://my.freenom.com) or you can use /etc/hosts 
update it with :

```
server-alias a.b.c.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Type of your Traefik Ingress Service is `NodePort`, you get to access to the port provided which will have a value from 30000-32000.

You can also configure it to be of type `LoadBalancer` and interface with a cloud-based Load Balancer.
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

Here's a very related question: [Should I use NodePort in my Traefik deployment on Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481979/should-i-use-nodeport-in-my-traefik-deployment-on-kubernetes)